# XMPP last activity time shows in strange form. How to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

I have added to the Bridging file XMPPLastActivity.h file and in Swift file I did the next:

```
let abc = XMPPLastActivity()
let a = abc.sendLastActivityQueryToJID(user.jid)
print("A is: \(a)")
```

but it returns me response like

```
1686F740-C50C-477B-BAE2-02C897826B97
```

How can I return it in human readable format?

**UPDATE**

Please, join to chat to help me: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90972/ios-errors-fixing

Answer (score 1):

You will get a response via the XMPP delegate. You need to implement:

```
func xmppLastActivityDidReceiveResponse(sender:XMPPLastActivity, response:XMPPIQ)
```

And get the time lag to now in seconds with:

```
let time : NSUInteger = response.lastActivitySeconds
```

Then it's NSDate all the way.

Comment: it doesn't give me anything =/ I try to print time, it doesn't print anything

Comment: I slightly guessed the translation to Swift from Objective-C so it could be wrong. If you have the library in there it should autocomplete though. You will need to set the delegate object before it will receive signals also.

Comment: can you help me with unread messages count in XMPP? I created all needed functions, but it returns me 0. Can you help me in chat, please?

Comment: Hi, can I contact you via email, please?